# Gmail markup for event booking not working

Tags: gmail, google-calendar-api, google-schemas

I am trying to send an email with event template to Gmail addresses that will create an event in the recipients Google Calendar. Tried doing this using a standard C# Console Application. Below is my code.

The emails are being received by the recipients successfully, but no event is getting created in the Calendar.

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EventReservation">
     <meta itemprop="reservationNumber" content="IO1234567"/>
     <link itemprop="reservationStatus" href="http://schema.org/Confirmed"/>
     <div itemprop="underName" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="John Smith"/>
      </div>
      <div itemprop="reservationFor" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Google I/O 2013"/>
        <time itemprop="startDate" datetime="2018-03-03T08:30:00-08:00"/>
        <div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
          <meta itemprop="name" content="Moscone Center"/>
          <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
            <meta itemprop="streetAddress" content="800 Howard St."/>
            <meta itemprop="addressLocality" content="San Francisco"/>
            <meta itemprop="addressRegion" content="CA"/>
            <meta itemprop="postalCode" content="94103"/>
        <meta itemprop="addressCountry" content="US"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>
      Dear John, thanks for booking your Google I/O ticket with us.
    </p>
    <p>
      BOOKING DETAILS<br/>
      Reservation number: IO12345<br/>
      Order for: John Smith<br/>
      Event: Google I/O 2013<br/>
      Start time: March 3rd 2018 8:00am PST<br/>
      Venue: Moscone Center, 800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103<br/>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please help me identify where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [JSON-LD format](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation), and also you need to make sure to register your site/product with Google to have your email address whitelisted, otherwise none of this will work and Google will ignore your schema's.

You can do that here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google